# "At Least version X" Nuget Dependency Declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning) is a bit confusing. How can I specify that I depend on AT LEAST version `1.2.0` of package XPTO? is it `<PackageReference Include="XPTO" Version="1.2" />`?

My intention is that if a version `1.2.1` or `1.3` or `2.0` comes along, it will restore the newest available, and not fixed to `1.2`.

When I use the `Version="1.2"` notation visual studio keeps warning me that an update is available.

Comment: What about `<PackageReference Include="XPTO" Version="*" />` ?

Comment: There's a lower bound here, version 1.0 won't work, it has to be at least 1.2. `*` means any, and if they are pulling from a private repo that doesn't have anything above 1.2, it will fail

Comment: I have digged in. Possible it would help <PackageReference Include="XPTO" Version="(1.2,)" />. More info you can find in msdn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges